# Xcode fails in build with "Compilation failed for data model at path" - and does not work with suggested StackOverFlow fixes to similar issues

Tags: xcode, svn, core-data

Hi my Xcode project at some point yesterday started failing to build with the error:

> Compilation failed for data model at path
>   '/Users/cooldocman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cooldocs-ejjarvdamwdcbbcpahhnbweztrmh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/cooldocs.app/cooldocs.momd/cooldocs.mom'

I did research on StackOverflow and other sites - and none of the suggested fixes to similar sounding issues have worked for me. The issue appears to be at the intersection of SVN, Xcode, Core Data and XCUserState, and I have tried a number of steps from info I found on StackOverflow and other sites, but still have not solved this.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. One stackoverflow article recommended to clean out the SImulator applications folder:
   So I  removed apps from under /Users/cooldocman/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications
   ... the error persisted ...
2. Another stackoverflow thread advised to remove the temp DerivedData folder.
   So I removed all folders under 
   /Users/cooldocman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
   (the folders in the error message i.e. /Users/cooldocman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cooldocs-ejjarvdamwdcbbcpahhnbweztrmhwere 
   therefore were deleted)
3. Another article said to remove the contents of the Archives folder ...
   /Users/cooldocman/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives

Still no luck even after steps 2 and 3

1. Even after all the cleanup, I still see when I grep contents of my project that a reference still exists to the old "cooldocs-ejjarvdamwdcbbcpahhnbweztrmh" folder...

   $ grep ejjarvdamwdcbbcpahhn */*/*/*/*/*
   Binary file trunk/cooldocs.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/cooldocman.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches

Now how do I clean *this* up?

PERHAPS THE SECRET I NEED IS HOW TO CLEAN UP THIS LEFTOVER xcuserdata and hopefully that will resolve the issue - or otherwise, to use a treasure hunt analogy, it may at least open the door to another mysterious tunnel that needs to be crawled down!  (and when I come out of that final cave is when I can start the actual work on what I really need to do!)

Thanks for reading and appreciate any help and insights from this group!

:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding to xcuserdatad folder, Why not just close your Xcode and delete it in Finder or Terminal? It's safe to do that. Next time you open the project with Xcode, It will recreate it for you .

Comment: @Bob_Cromwell I tried this but the next time I open I get a nil access error from my NSManagedObjectModel

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and none of the suggestions worked. I finally deleted the entire directory which had my project and cloned it again from Github and it fixed the issue. It's possible that some file that was git ignored wasn't getting reverted, but I didn't have time to find out which file it was.